# Tar baby in German?

Tags: translation

How would you translate the term `tar baby`?

I know the translated title of a book by Toni Morrison is `Teerbaby` but that doesn't really mean anything for someone who didn't read the book. In English however, this is a word that's actually [in the dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tar%20baby?s=t).

Is there something like that? I couldn't find anything so far.

If nothing exists, how would you express it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the term "Zwickmühle", which roughly matches your dictionary description:

https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zwickm%C3%BChle

Comment: I am not sure that's exactly the same. You can walk away from a tarbaby, which is not true if you are _stuck between a rock and a hard place_ or got into _a catch-22 situation_ ...

Comment: @Ingmar The linked dictionary entry of tarbaby is in line with this. "[...]almost impossible [...] to break away from."

Comment: Well, it doesn't match my (native) understanding of the term. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

Ich fürchte dass es überhaupt keine gute und griffige Übersetzung gibt. Joel Chandler Harris ist in Europa dafür einfach nicht bekannt genug. Es bleibt also nur eine Umschreibung.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. How would you express it?

Comment: Depends on context. Do you have an original sentence? Maybe something like "eine Situation, aus der man ohne Flecken auf der weißen Weste nicht mehr herauskommt".

Comment: I heard this verbally. The conversation was about a third person and the sentence was something like "he is a tar baby, I would not rely on his help."

Answer (score 1):

What lupor said is pretty close. A "Zwickmühle" describes a situation that is almost hopeless. Like choosing between *a rock and a hard place* (German: Lebra und Cholera; two diseases).

I think there is no other way but describing it metaphorically. One way of explaining it may be a spider web. Once you got in it is hard to get out.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the title of an English novel a German publisher would probably choose a totally different title as tar baby doesn't tell Germans anything. In the novel the term tar baby may be used and translated as "Teerbaby" but the translation would probably insert a sentence or two to explain the expression.